# Interview question: Are you familiar with linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've ran into this question a couple times where people ask me if I am familiar with linux.  What does this usually imply?  I know how to navigate a command prompt in Ubuntu, edit files, compile c programs, but I feel like I am only scratching the surface.  Any tips on how one becomes a guru in linux?  Thanks for any advice.  Hope this question isn't too subjective.

Comment: You're asking two radically different questions: What do people mean when they ask a question? You should ask them what they mean, not us. And how can you become a linux guru -- read books on the subject, spend a lot of time doing IT work on Linux, get a job in a Linux shop.

Comment: I've removed the c tag since this isn't a question about C programming or otherwise relevant to C.

Answer (score 3):

Strange question, it depends why someone is asking. There's no limit to the amount of stuff you can know about Linux but it sounds like you certainly know more than the average joe off the street. I'd say you 'know' linux to most people, but be wary of saying that at a LUG.

Comment: remember the hacker purity test http://www.armory.com/tests/hacker.html ?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't, "are you a guru in Linux". It's, "are you familiar with Linux."

Most people expect you to stretch things a *little* in your job interview. You can safely say you're familiar with it. In the worst case, you'll just need to read up on it the first day on the job :-)